# How do I assign a open workbook and worksheet to variables?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a script that will open a directory, select the file and assign the workbook name and worksheet name to variables. When the workbook opens the file, I'm trying to get VBA to assign that file to a variable along with the first worksheet.

```
Workbook Variable: DataFile_Workbook
Worksheet Variable: DataFile_Sheet
```

Currently my code is :

```
Sub OpenWorkbooksAndChangeNames
Workbooks.open("\\datafiles\*.xlsx" <- this opens the file in the directory

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
**Set wb = DataFile_Workbook
Set ws = DataFile_Sheet**  <- this is where im trying to assign the workbook name open from line 2 to "DataFile_Workbook" and "DataFile_Sheet" as the first worksheet name.
```

Comment: `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(DataFile_Sheet)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the object when you open it. You will need the know the filename from the wildcard, so use the `Dir` function for that. Note the `Dir` function returns only a filename and not a path for it.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sFilename As String
sFilename = Dir("\\datafiles\*.xlsx")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\datafiles\" & sFilename)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

'assign them to variables (given your example, there is no need to do this)
Dim DataFile_Workbook As String
DataFile_Workbook = wb.Name
Dim DataFile_Sheet As String
DataFile_Sheet = ws.Name

' show the names 
MsgBox DataFile_Workbook ' or just use wb.Name
MsgBox DataFile_Sheet    ' or just use ws.Name
```

Understand that if there is more than one file in that folder that matches the wildcard, it will just open the first one it finds no matter how many there are.

If you know the filename....

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\datafiles\" & DataFile_Workbook)
```

Comment: Just understanding where did you assign WB and WS as Workbook Variable: "DataFile_Workbook" and Worksheet Variable: "DataFile_Sheet". I want to VBA to assign the file name open from DIR to "DataFile_Workbook" and  and the first worksheet from the file to "DataFile_Sheet"

Comment: Not sure i understand. Is `DataFile_Workbook` a String then? Where is that defined and assigned a value? You already know the filename? If so, then why are you using a wildcard?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain. I don't know the file name, I'm opening the only file in the Directory and assigning the file name & first sheet name to variables.

Comment: OK, then refresh the page and re-read the updated answer. It's all explained there.